# is it possible to have type hints without LET?

Tags: clojure

This is my code (an example):

```
(def foo (.java_method java_object))
(debug "result of method bar() on object foo: " (.bar foo))
```

I get a warning (`foo` is of type `FooType` in Java):

```
Reflection warning, example/test.clj:2 - call to bar can't be resolved
```

I can remove the warning with this type hint:

```
(def foo (.java_method java_object))
(debug "result of method bar() on object foo: " (.bar ^FooType foo))
```

This works, but I have to do this type hinting every time I use `foo`. Another solution would be to use `let`, but it creates extra indentation level, which I'd like to avoid. Is it possible to do something like?:

```
(def foo (.java_method java_object))
(set-type foo FooType)
(debug "result of method bar() on object foo: " (.bar foo))
```

Answer (score 1):

No. For associating compile-time metadata like type-hints with named values, use let.

Answer (score 1):

You can associate type hint with `def`.

```
(def ^FooType foo (.java_method java_object))
```

### UPDATE:

Example:

```
user=> (set! *warn-on-reflection* true)
true
user=> (import java.util.Hashtable)
java.util.Hashtable
user=> (def ^Hashtable table (Hashtable.))
#'user/table
user=> (.put table "one" 1)
nil
user=> (.put table "two" 2)
nil
```

Comment: it doesn't help, in the next line this type is forgotten

Comment: Is it? I tried `(def ^String a "Hello")  (.toString a)` and there is no reflection warning

Comment: perhaps `toString` exists in all Java object? :)

Comment: if you remove type hint.. you will get reflector warning

Comment: I agree it should work. Can you give a reproducible example (using classes from the JDK)?

Comment: @yegor tested Ankur code with Clojure 1.2.0 it works. What did you try?